# django-nvd3 dependency on django version

Tags: python, django, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to use django-nvd3 with django.
I copied the line chart example from http://django-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/classes-doc/line-chart.html. But it is not working. I am getting following error

"simple_tag() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'"

I am guessing this is due to version incompatibility. I am using django version 1.3 and django-nvd3 version 0.6

The reason I am guessing version mismatch is that I had to modify the example template 
The example template had following line

```
<link media="all" href="{% static 'nvd3/src/nv.d3.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then I got "Invalid block tag: 'static'" error.
I replaced the href as `"/static/nvd3/src/nv.d3.css"` and I got that error resolved.

Here is template file

```
{% load static %}
<link media="all" href="/static/nvd3/src/nv.d3.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src='/static/d3/d3.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/static/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js'></script>

{% load nvd3_tags %}
<head>
    {% load_chart charttype chartdata "linechart_container" True "%d %b %Y %H" %}
</head>
<body>
    {% include_container "linechart_container" 400 600 %}
</body>
```

Pls help me get over the "simple_tag()...." error.

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Updated the question to include the complete template file

Answer (score 0):

Try change

`{% load_chart charttype chartdata "linechart_container" True "%d %b %Y %H" %}`

to

`{% load_chart charttype chartdata "linechart_container" kw_extra "%d %b %Y %H" %}`